# doveadm pw may generate invalid password if a special charactare is used

Tags: dovecot, password, ubuntu-14.04

I have a dovecot server running on an Ubuntu 14.04 server, which reads the login-data (user/domain/password) from a mysql-database.

The passwords are saved as salted SHA256 hashes. To generate these, I use the command `doveadm pw -s SHA512-CRYPT`. According to [Dovecot wiki Authentication PasswordSchemes](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/PasswordSchemes) page, the command uses glibcs `crypt()` function.

Now, when I use a password without special characters (Uppercase/Lowercase letters and numbers) like "t3st", I can successfully login to the according mail-account. But as soon as the password contains any other characters (e.g. `t3$t`), I can't login anymore. doveadm will in both cases return seemingly valid hashes (e.g. `$6$iADbo7odiTlVjYgl$fi0X/kIHSUmAHAAiHIsXU6ow3j9dshL9mX.VTCDFOBMt.aV/.ZWpadLk3AFPD30EZ7SiyaqAR66YlTPoeQrcH/`).

I tried logging in to the server via Thunderbird and an web-based mail-interface, with both giving the same error-message in the log-files:

> dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts in 2 secs) ...

I also tried using the MD5-CRYPT "encryption", with the same results.

Comment: Do you really use version 1? You are linking the wiki for that version...

Comment: Yes, I use version 2. I changed the link. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The doveadm pw documentation contains the following information:

"You should enclose the password hash in single quotes, if it contains one or more dollar signs ($)."

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding

```
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_verbose_passwords = yes
```

to your Dovecot configuration. Thus you will see what passwords dovecot actually receives from the clients and compares from passdb.